# How to launch an exe by command prompt and get text from command prompt window

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, command, command-prompt

`jarsigner.exe` takes a parameter and prints some text to console:

```
string command = "jarsigner.exe -verify test.jar";
system(command.c_str());
```

when I run this code, command prompt window appears and
it prints `jar is verified` or `jar is unsigned` to console.

How can I get this result string  from the console?

Answer (score 2):

You can try [ReadConsoleOutputCharacter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684969%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

I used [Google](http://www.google.com) to find [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/190351).

EDIT: Does `jarsigner` not return error codes? Like `0` on success and `1` on failure? You could use `CreateProcess` and trap the return code.

Comment: Using Google to find answers to questions?

Comment: exitCode returns 1 in both cases

Answer (score 1):

You could redirect stdout to to a file (jarsigner.exe > outfile.txt) and then parse the contents of the file using a utility like a perl or shell script.

Alternatively, you can redirect stdout in your application using the dup, [_open_osfhandle](http://www.halcyon.com/~ast/dload/guicon.htm), or [freopen](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/freopen.html) functions.

Comment: actually instead of system() function i have to use ShellExecute function how can i redirect jarsigner.exe's console output to a text file.

Comment: it works by  system("jarsigner.exe >out.txt");
but i want to hide console, only output text is needed

Answer (score 0):

i created new process and redirect its stdout to text file, it works.

```
STARTUPINFO si;
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;

HANDLE hOutFile;

ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(si) );
ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi) );
ZeroMemory( &sa, sizeof(sa) );

si.cb = sizeof(si);
si.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE;
si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW | STARTF_USESTDHANDLES ;

sa.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
sa.bInheritHandle = true;

// Create output file and get file handle
hOutFile  = CreateFile ( TEXT(outFilePath.c_str()),
        FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
        0,
        &sa, // provide SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
        CREATE_ALWAYS,
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
        NULL);

// Assign StartInfo StdOutput to file handle
si.hStdOutput = hOutFile ;

LPTSTR szCmdline = TEXT( command.c_str() );
 if( !CreateProcess( NULL,   // No module name (use command line)
    szCmdline,        // Command line
    NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
    NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable
    true,          // Set handle inheritance to TRUE
    0,              // No creation flags
    NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
    TEXT(jarSignerExeDir.c_str()), // Use jarSignerExeDir FOR starting directory
    &si,            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
    &pi )           // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
)
{
   ShowMessage( "CreateProcess failed (%d).\n" + GetLastError() );
}

// Wait until child process exits.
WaitForSingleObject( pi.hProcess, INFINITE );

// Close process,thread and file handles.
CloseHandle( pi.hProcess );
CloseHandle( pi.hThread );
CloseHandle(hOutFile);
```